# How to get order relation in laravel

Tags: laravel, relationship

I have 1 relation

```
Order(id, user_id, total_price)
```

```
OrderDetail(order_id, product_id, num_of_product)
```

```
Product(id, title, num_of_existed, price)
```

Ask: How to get order across template:

```php
order:[
   id: 1,
   user_id:1,
   total_price:1.1,
   order_detail:[
     id:1,
     order_id:1,
     book_id:1,
     num_of_product:10
     product:[
      id:1,
      title: 'abc',
      num_of_existed: 100,
      price: 0.1
     ]
   ]
]
```

Comment: have u created the relationship between them?

Answer (score 2):

Create relationship in your `Order` model as ,

```
public function order_details()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\OrderDetail','order_id','id');
}
```

In your `Orderdetail` model,

```
public function product_details()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product','id','product_id'); // first foreign key then local key
}
```

In your controller

```
$orders = Order::all(); 
return view('view_name',compact('orders'));
```

In the view

```
@foreach ($orders as $order)
    @if ($order->order_details)
        {{$order->order_details->num_of_product}}
        @if($order->order_details->product_details)
            {{$order->order_details->product_details->title}}
            {{$order->order_details->product_details->num_of_existed}}
            {{$order->order_details->product_details->price}}
        @endif
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it via laravel eloquent relationship, to define relationship you will have 3 models like Order, OrderDetail,Product related to corresponding tables.

On your order model:

```
    public function OrderDetail()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\OrderDetail','order_id');
    }
```

On your OrderDetail model:

```
    public function Order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Order','order_id');
    }
    public function Product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product','product_id');
    }
```

Then on your controller

```
    public function foo(){
        $orders=Order::all(); //remember to use 'App\Order'
        return view('filename',compact('orders'));
    }
```

Now on your blade, you will find all related table data just by chaining orders

```
    @foreach ($orders as $order)
        @if ($order->OrderDetail)
            @if($order->OrderDetail->Product)
                {{$order->OrderDetail->Product->title}}
            @endif
        @endif
    @endforeach
```

for more see [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)